# Can someone help me with my code? I'm tying to use selenium and web driver to be able to click on articles from googles new site using the XPATHs?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to write a script that allows me to click on an article based on randomized categories on googles news site. I'm doing this using selenium for educational purposes but I can't seem to the get the code right. I'm sure I'm using the proper XPaths but it doesn't seem to want to stay open and keeps crashing.

```
BUSINESS = 'CAAqJggKIiBDQkFTRWdvSUwyMHZNRGx6TVdZU0FtVnVHZ0pWVXlnQVAB?hl=enUS&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen'
WORLD = 'CAAqJggKIiBDQkFTRWdvSUwyMHZNRGx1YlY4U0FtVnVHZ0pWVXlnQVAB?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen'

categories = [WORLD, BUSINESS]
random_category = random.choice(categories)

# Navigate to Google News
driver.get(f"https://news.google.com/topics/{random_category}")
time.sleep(5)

if random_category == WORLD:
    w = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='yDmH0d']/c-wiz[3]/div/main/c-wiz/div[2]/c-wiz/div/c-wiz[1]/c-wiz/div/article")
    w.click()
    time.sleep(5)
elif random_category == BUSINESS:
    b = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='c2642-panel']/div/c-wiz/div/c-wiz[1]/c-wiz/div/article/div[1]/a")
    b.click()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was your locators... :)

You were grabbing too much and ended up getting locators that were randomly generated. There's a much simpler locator that you can use for both world and business articles so I simplified the code.

This navigates to the random category on the site, grabs the first article and prints the title, and then clicks the article link.

```
import random
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

BUSINESS = 'CAAqJggKIiBDQkFTRWdvSUwyMHZNRGx6TVdZU0FtVnVHZ0pWVXlnQVAB?hl=enUS&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen'
WORLD = 'CAAqJggKIiBDQkFTRWdvSUwyMHZNRGx1YlY4U0FtVnVHZ0pWVXlnQVAB?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen'

categories = [WORLD, BUSINESS]
random_category = random.choice(categories)

# Navigate to Google News
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(f"https://news.google.com/topics/{random_category}")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
a = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "article > div > a")))
print(f"Title: {a[0].get_attribute('aria-label')}")
a[0].click()
```

Comment: Dude thank you so much. Ive spent literal hours trying to solve this puzzle of code. Thank you man , you're the best!

Comment: also where did you find the CSS_SELECTOR code for the articles?

Comment: I just looked at the HTML. Each article is inside an ARTICLE tag. From there it's just finding the A tag that is the link to the article and filling in the necessary pieces between the ARTICLE and the A to make sure we're finding the right A.